# Access BO repository using SSIS or linked server

Tags: sql, ssis, business-intelligence, linked-server, business-objects

Does anybody know if it is possible (and how) to connect to BO repository from an "Microsoft tool"?

I need to query the `CI_INFOOBJECTS` catalog. Ideally I would like to connect using  linked servers or SSIS packages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I took a different approach by building a assembly to get the info I need and access it from my SSIS package

Answer (score 2):

It would probably help to know which version of BO you have, however a [fairly recent article](http://alteksolutions.com/wp/index.php/2010/03/using-query-builder-to-explore-your-businessobjects-repository/) basically says that a) it's a binary format so there's no 'direct' way to query it; b) but you can query it from BO itself; and c) the BO Enterprise SDK provides documentation on how to get the information from .NET.